# Navigation bar background color - translucency is no

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to change the background color of the navigation bar to a solid green.

Rule: I can't mess with the AppDelegate :)

I've tried:

```
//It's green but it's translucent 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];

//It's white, first line has no effect
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

//Same result as case 1
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.0f];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];

//Too dark
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];

//Only affects the back button's color:
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

So any ideas?

Thank you, didn't see there was barTintColor and TintColor as well. Accepting earliest answer.

Comment: didi you use the storyboard? then select the viewcontroller and in the inspector under simulated metrics set the top bar to opaque navigation bar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this line of code in your viewController didLoad method

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0f/255.0f green:149.0f/255.0f blue:174.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one,

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0f green:52.0/255.0f blue:36.0/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code may be this will help you.

```
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yourcolor];
```

Answer (score 0):

use barTintColor property of navigationBar